# Alignment in android Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I am using linear layout with 2 textviews, 4 buttons, 1 seekbar,1 image view. If I am place those textviews,buttons, etc. in a linear layout the alignment is fine in android phone. While I am running the same code in android tablet, alignment is not proper. Why this alignment is not proper in tablet.? I have created the textviews,buttons etc by java code. Even I am specifying the two text views horizontally by settings the left margin of the second text view by **devicewidth/2** having the difference in android phone and tablet. I need to align like the below.

```
 TextView1                            TextView2
 Button1 Button2 Button3 Button4      SeekBar  ImageView
```

Here is my code.

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textViewLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
    TextView TextView1=new TextView(this);
    TextView1.setText("Text1");
    textViewParams1.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
    textViewParams1.setMargins(60, 20, 40, 10);
    textViewLayout.addView(chooseColorTextView, textViewParams1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView TextView2=new TextView(this);
    TextView2.setText("Text2");
    int width=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    textViewParams2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;     
    textViewParams2.setMargins((width/2), 20, 40, 10);
    textViewLayout.addView(strokeWidthTextView, textViewParams2);

    parentlinearLayout.addView(textViewLayout, textViewLayoutParams);
```

In the next linear layout, I have added the 4 buttons,seekbar and image view. But facing problems in alignment.

Comment: try to post a diagram or picture of your desired result, let's see if I can help...but I recommend to go the XML way

Answer (score 2):

I advise to create complex layout that must be rendered on different screen sizes in XML rather than programmatically, so you can have two different main.xml in res/layout and in res/layout-large and the system would pick up the correct one depending on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight and weightSum in XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- First column -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight=".5" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> ... </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Second column -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight=".5" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> ... </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will produce a dynamically resizing 2 column layout. If you want the divide shorter or longer, change .5 to .3 and .7 for a 30/70% split etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about wrap_content and other android controls. Also read about dpi of tablets. Due to resolution appearance changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a **TableLayout** ? its the one you need to manage cells alignement:

All that you need is in the span attribute to make cells use multiple columns.

```
TableLayout myLayout = new TableLayout(myContext);

TableRow row1 = new TableRow(myContext);
TableRow.LayoutParams layouparams1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layouparams1.span = 4;
row1.setLayoutParams = layouparams1 ;

TableRow.LayoutParams layouparams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layouparams2.span = 2;
TableRow row2 = new TableRow(myContext);
row2.setLayoutParams = layouparams2 ;


//then create and add your childs to each row :
...
row1.addView(text1);
row1.addView(text1);

row1.addView(button1);
row1.addView(button2);
row1.addView(button3);
row1.addView(button4);
row1.addView(seekbar);
row1.addView(imageView);

myLayout.addView(row1);
myLayout.addView(row2);
```

also consider adding **layout_weight** on children to manage the space they left to each other.